# JAVA JPA UUID passing as List

Tags: java, jpa, spring-boot

I would like to pass list of UUID in JPA.

Given below is my code

#### Entity class

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity  {
    @Id
    @Convert(converter = UUIDConverter.class)
    private UUID id;


    @Convert(converter = UUIDConverter.class)
    private UUID someUuid;

    // getters and setters

}
```

#### Repository class:

```
public interface MyEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, UUID> {
    List<MyEntity> findBySomeUuidIn(List<UUID> someUUIDs);
}
```

But I am getting error

```
Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: uuid = record
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 234
Error Code: 0
```

while calling `myEntityRepository.findBySomeUuidIn(someUUIdList)`.

Please help. Thanks

Comment: you should add more details.  Your Entity class, repository etc

Comment: You need to add uuid-ossp extension to the database using query `CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp" SCHEMA public` or provide the actual query which caused this exception.

Comment: @pvpkiran I have added my code

Comment: so now go to the JPA provider log and see what SQL is being invoked (that then throws that exception ...)

Comment: @DN1 I have checked the query. It looks fine. I have updated the exception that I am getting in the question.

Comment: When I did the query using `@Query` it is working fine. Not sure why it is happening.

Comment: The query isn't fine otherwise you wouldn't get an exception! Why not post it (and the schema for reference)

Comment: @JoelGeorge which database do you use?

Comment: @Mara database is postgres.

Answer (score 1):

As your error says you might need to cast your parameter. E.x.

```
SELECT * FROM MyEntity obj WHERE obj.someUuid = CAST(:someUuid AS uuid)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this, but as per the [Querying with a UUID in WHERE clause has issue with postgresql](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/5329) it says in JPA models UUID columns need to be annotated with `@Type(type="org.hibernate.type.PostgresUUIDType")`

A better discussion that talks about need for specifying `Type` as JDBC doesn’t include UUIDs as one of its generic SQL types [Switching Hibernate’s UUID Type Mapping per Database](https://zorq.net/b/2012/04/21/switching-hibernates-uuid-type-mapping-per-database/)

You may want to try and see if that helps.